# Swift: check whether compiler supports conditional conformance

Tags: swift, xcode

With XCode 9.3 the swift compiler introduced conditional conformance, allowing us to compare two optionals.

We are working on a library that used to support Swift 3.2 and Swift 4.0 and where we had to define the following comparator for dictionaries:

```
fileprivate func ==(lhs:[String: NSObject]?, rhs: [String:NSObject]?) -> Bool {
    var match = true
    if let lhs = lhs {
        if let rhs = rhs {
            match = lhs == rhs
        } else {
            match = false
       }
    }
    return match
}
```

In Swift 3.3 and Swift 4.1 this comparator is no longer valid and cause an infinite loop on the line that says

```
match = lhs == rhs
```

Where the matcher now calls itself.
It is a library so we can not force our clients to use the newest XCode version, yet.

Is there a way to check whether the compiler supports conditional conformance?

Comment: this line `lhs == rhs` recall your  func `func ==`

Comment: If the data of this type `[String: NSObject]?` always do not need to work custom optionals this is equatable reed this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable

Comment: This is new in Swift 3.3 and Swift 4.1, before `[String:NSObject]?` is not equatable

Comment: what is use  swift version ??

Answer (score 1):

Newer Swift version provide a built-in `==` operator for dictionaries as well as for optionals, and also provides coercion of non-optional types to optional types (see remarks below).

Therefore I think the easiest version would be to simply kick out the whole `==` func in newer Swift versions:

```
#if !swift(>=3.3)  // check the correct version, I'm not sure about 3.3 or newer
func ==(lhs:[String:Int]?, rhs: [String:Int]?) -> Bool  {
    print ("check same \(lhs) == \(rhs)")
    var match = true
    if let lhs = lhs {
        if let rhs = rhs {
            match = lhs == rhs
        } else {
            match = false
        }
    }
    return match
}
#endif


var a:[String:NSObject]? = ["a":"c" as NSObject]
var b:[String:NSObject]? = ["a":"c" as NSString]

print (a == b)
```

---

Remarks:

The problem is that in the current Swift version, an function that expects `Optional`s can also be called by the corresponding non-optional parameter(s), like here:

```
func consumesOptional(value: Int?) -> Int {
    print ("consuming \(String(describing: value))")
    return value!
}

let x: Int = 1
let y = consumesOptional(value: x)
print(y)    // "consuming Optional(1)"
```

So if you create a `func ==` that takes optional parameters, and then (in your `if let` cascade call `==` with the non optional types, this will lead to a recursion, as correctly stated in the comments below.

For more details, see [SE-0121](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0123-disallow-value-to-optional-coercion-in-operator-arguments.md)

Comment: This unfortunately still ends up in an infinite loop, because the same method will call the == with optionals again.

Comment: Also: Swift >=3.3 doesn't work either, because swift 4.0 does not support it, only swift 4.1 -_-

Comment: @Infinite You are absolutely right. Please check my modified answer.